# C# streamreader, delimiter.

Tags: c#, streamreader

What I have is a txt file that is huge, 60MB.  I need to read each line and produce a file, split based on a delimiter.  I'm having no issue reading the file or producing the file, my complication comes from the delimiter, it can't see the delimiter.  If anybody could offer a suggestion on how to read that delimiter I would be so grateful.

delimiter = Ç

```
public void file1()
{
    string betaFilePath = @"C:\dtable.txt";
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(betaFilePath, FileMode.Open))
    using (StreamReader rdr = new StreamReader(fs))
    {
        while (!rdr.EndOfStream)
        {
            string[] betaFileLine = rdr.ReadLine().Split('Ç');
            {
                sb.AppendLine(betaFileLine[0] + "ç" + betaFileLine[1] + betaFileLine[2] + "ç" + betaFileLine[3] + "ç" + betaFileLine[4] + "ç" + betaFileLine[5] + "ç" + betaFileLine[6] + "ç" + betaFileLine[7] + "ç" + betaFileLine[8] + "ç" + betaFileLine[9] + "ç" + betaFileLine[10] + "ç");
            }
        }
    }
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"C:\testarea\load1.txt", FileMode.Create))
    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fs))
    {
        writer.Write(sb.ToString());
    }
}
```

Small update:

```
string[] betaFileLine = rdr.ReadLine().Split('Ç');
```

It's not able to split on the charecter Ç.  When i debug it, it comes out to be an unreadable charecter.

Guys, thanks for the help you defiently pointed my in the right direction.

Changing:

```
using (StreamReader rdr = new StreamReader(fs))
```

To:

```
using (StreamReader rdr = new StreamReader((fs),Encoding.Default))
```

Fixed it.

Comment: What do you mean with "it can't see the delimiter"? And what exactly goes wrong?

Comment: string[] betaFileLine = rdr.ReadLine().Split('Ç'); 

It's not able to split on the charecter Ç.  When i debug it, it comes out to be an unreadable charecter.

Comment: I think you should accept David M's answer.

Comment: Please mark an answer for someone who might stumble upon similar problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure your `StreamReader` uses the same text encoding as your text file. The constructor can take a second parameter to indicate the encoding to use.

Comment: Thats the thing, it see's the line just fine, it doesnt seem the delimiter.

Comment: I'e tried changing it to using (StreamReader rdr = new StreamReader((fs),Encoding.ASCII)) but this just results in the Ç being read as a ?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are splitting on Ç but adding ç.  Not something as simple as replacing the uppercase delimiter with the lowercase or vice versa.

Comment: Doesnt get past the line split.

Comment: Does the dtable.txt file contain the Ç character?